# Datatable export with selected rows by checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables with tabletools on a large table which is filled via ajax request.

When user selects several rows, it shows them as selected in the table.

How can i tell the csv/pdf export to ONLY export the selected rows?

Thanks in advance

jsfiddle.net/svbhatt/abhbs4x8/1057/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/svbhatt/abhbs4x8/1057/  JSfiddle link

Comment: Your fiddle gives the error `(index):150 Uncaught TypeError: table.button is not a function`

Comment: Yaa, Actually that was a problem. @DelightedD0D

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `exportOptions` -

```
{
  extend: 'pdf',
  exportOptions: {
    rows: { selected: true }
  }
}
```